# about dropbox's restfull api. why both action belong to different kinds

Tags: java, rest, dropbox

all
I take a look at all rest apis for dropbox. There are two types: files(put, metadata.share, etc.) and opts(such as /fileops/move,/fileopt/copy, etc). But I am very puzzled that:
why restore/share method belong to file type. Thus the create folder belong to file opertions type? Generally speak, I think they are both actions. Why followed such types ?
Anybody knows? Thanks in advance.

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#fileops-move

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation states:

> File operations
>
> The variousfileops calls provide the standard file operations. Files and folders can be moved, copied, or deleted. Folders can be created.

The fileopts are standard actions. Actions like share are none standard file actions.

Comment: Thanks. I can't understand why delete path not belong to standard file actions.

Comment: It does belong to the standard file operations? https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#fileops-delete

Comment: File operations includes: copy, move, delete, create_folder.

Comment: why put/post not belong to standard actions? Can you give more clues? Many thanks to you!

Comment: The various fileops calls provide the ability to manipulate the metadata directory hierachy. Files and folders can be moved, copied, or deleted, and folders can be created.
I query old api doc. Maybe this is root cause. Do you confirm it?

Comment: I never worked with dropbox's api but I think standard file operations are file operations found in most file systems. PUT and GET seem to represent HTTP operations thus not related to file operations. I think this is well explained in the documentation.

Comment: I agree with you. I can think that : "manipulate the metadata directory hierachy" actions are standard file options.